# Kafka streams application wants to retrieve the wrong schema

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We see errors like this in one of our Kafka streams applications:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_6, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=mytopicXYZ, partition=6, offset=465, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Protobuf schema for id 571
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.toKafkaException(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:253)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.AbstractKafkaProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaProtobufDeserializer.java:177)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaProtobufDeserializer.java:76)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaProtobufDeserializer.java:27)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.deserialize(ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.java:58)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.deserialize(ValueAndTimestampDeserializer.java:31)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.valueFrom(StateSerdes.java:163)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.outerValue(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:427)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$get$5(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:318)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:887)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.get(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:318)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ReadOnlyKeyValueStoreFacade.get(ReadOnlyKeyValueStoreFacade.java:35)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CompositeReadOnlyKeyValueStore.get(CompositeReadOnlyKeyValueStore.java:56)
    at com.lgt.pdcl.avaloqminer.currency.CurrencyService.getCurrencyEntry(CurrencyService.java:54)
    at com.lgt.pdcl.avaloqminer.currency.CurrencyService.getCurrencyEntryByKey(CurrencyService.java:50)
    at com.lgt.pdcl.avaloqminer.currency.CurrencyService.getCurrency(CurrencyService.java:28)
    at com.lgt.pdcl.avaloqminer.mapper.DocCordMapper.map(DocCordMapper.java:490)
    at com.lgt.pdcl.avaloqminer.mapper.DocCordMapper.map(DocCordMapper.java:194)
    at com.lgt.pdcl.avaloqminer.mapper.DocCordMapper.process(DocCordMapper.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:157)
```

A schema with id 571 doesn't exist in the schema registry so obviously it can't be retrieved. The problem is that in the events for this topic a totally different schema id is stored and that one exists in the registry so on the Kafka server and the registry side everything seems to be OK. Somehow the streams application has the wrong id but we have no idea where this id is coming from.

We tried to delete the state stores, the id that the streams application wants to retrieve changed but is still wrong.

Comment: Have you tried remove the schemas from the state stores?

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from `deserialize`; thus the schema-id is coming from the data itself; the schema-id is encoded in a prefix to the serialized value bytes.

> We tried to delete the state stores,

Well, the state store is backed up by a changelog topic. Thus, if you have corrupted data in the changelog, it would just repopulate into the store from the changelog.